VPC Lambda in private subnet, give S3 access
I have the following code, which sets up an AWS stack and creates a StepFunction, where one of the steps is an AWS Lambda function that is deployed into the VPC. I am looking to have the Lambda function access the S3 bucket and also have access to the EFS (ElasticFileSystem)
export interface WorkflowStackProps extends NestedStackProps {
  readonly config: Config;
  readonly bucketArn: string;
  readonly vpc: IVpc;
  readonly efs: IFileSystem;
  readonly accessPoint: AccessPoint;
}

export class WorkflowStack extends NestedStack {
  sfn: StateMachine;
  constructor(s: Construct, id: string, props: WorkflowStackProps) {
    super(s, id, props);
    this.sfn = this.generateSftpS3Sfn(props, `${id}Main`);
  }

  generateSftpS3Sfn(
    props: WorkflowStackProps,
    id: string,
    // emailSfn: StateMachine,
  ): StateMachine {
    const succeed = new Succeed(this, `${id}Success`);
    const fail = new Fail(this, `${id}Failed`);
    // S3 Bucket
    const bucket = Bucket.fromBucketArn(
      this,
      'SFTPBucket',
      props.bucketArn,
    )
    // Lambda Functions
    const fileProcessorFn = new Function(this, 'FileProcessor', {
      runtime: Runtime.PROVIDED_AL2023,
      architecture: Architecture.ARM_64,
      timeout: Duration.minutes(15),
      memorySize: 2048,
      handler: "bootstrap",
      code: Code.fromAsset(
        path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'dist', 'file-processor-fn.zip'),
      ),
      vpc: props.vpc,
      vpcSubnets: { subnets: props.vpc.isolatedSubnets },
      filesystem: LambdaFileSystem.fromEfsAccessPoint(props.accessPoint, '/mnt/efs'),
      environment: {
        // STEP_FUNCTION_ARN: emailSfn.stateMachineArn,
      },
    });

    // Allow the fileProcessorFn to Read/Write to the SFTP bucket
    bucket.grantReadWrite(fileProcessorFn);
    fileProcessorFn.addToRolePolicy(new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      actions: [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl",
        "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
      ],
      resources: [
        bucket.bucketArn,
        bucket.arnForObjects("*"),
      ],
    }));

When I run the SFN, I get an error
time="2024-06-21T13:53:28Z" level=error msg="error in downloading file: AccessDenied: Access Denied\n\tstatus code: 403, request id: GHABW556MMWA0ETZ, host id: 9zrD7qv3at6Z8qvxkc0JfG3mThvTyfYh6o4j8I+ap45VBcv0XferFmOJQ9qV//pPWwHcxqt2re4=" bucket=sftp-eu-west-1 key=home/nkhine/PROJECT_2024-05-23_49a554e0-1cbf-437f-9d46-21bf31c86e68.csv

When I created the VPC in the main stack, I have added the S3 endpoint
import { WorkflowStack } from '../workflow/stack';
import { Config } from '../../config'
import TaggingStack from '../../tagging'

export interface TransferStackProps extends StackProps {
  config: Config
}

export class TransferStack extends TaggingStack {
  // public readonly vpc: Vpc;
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: TransferStackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props)
    const config = props.config.stage
    const account = Stack.of(this).account
    const region = Stack.of(this).region
    const accountsArray = config.accounts.map((account) => account.id);
    // VPC
    const flowLogBucket = Bucket.fromBucketArn(
      this,
      'FlowLogBucket',
      config.vpc.flowLogBucketArn,
    )
    const vpc = new Vpc(this, `vpc-${region}-${account}`, {
      ipAddresses: IpAddresses.cidr(config.vpc.cidr),
      enableDnsSupport: true,
      enableDnsHostnames: true,
      maxAzs: config.vpc.maxAzs,
      gatewayEndpoints: {
        // Keep S3 <-> Apps traffic and
        // ECR <-> Apps traffic in the VPC to reduce data transfer costs
        S3: { service: GatewayVpcEndpointAwsService.S3 },
      },
    })
...

    // S3 Bucket
    const sftpBucket = new Bucket(this, 'sftpBucket', {
      bucketName: `sftp-${account}-${region}`,
      encryption: BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
      blockPublicAccess: BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      accessControl: BucketAccessControl.LOG_DELIVERY_WRITE,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      autoDeleteObjects: true,
      versioned: true,
    })

...

    // Workflows
    const scanFileSystem = clamscan.node.tryFindChild('ScanFileSystem') as IFileSystem;
    if (scanVpc && scanFileSystem) {
      // Create a Access Point for the EFS to be used to store the modified OID file that is sent to SharePoint
      const accessPoint = new AccessPoint(this, 'LambdaAccessPoint', {
        fileSystem: scanFileSystem,
        createAcl: {
          ownerGid: '1000',
          ownerUid: '1000',
          permissions: '750',
        },
        path: '/workflow',
        posixUser: {
          gid: '1000',
          uid: '1000',
        },
      });
      const workflowStack = new WorkflowStack(this, 'Workflow', {
        config: props.config,
        bucketArn: sftpBucket.bucketArn,
        vpc: scanVpc,
        efs: scanFileSystem,
        accessPoint: accessPoint,
      });
...


If I add the function out of the VPC everything works and the FileProcessFn is able to read the S3 file, but not when I add it to the VPC.
What am I missing?
Any advice is much appreciated.
